# Two tables can be merged when if two key columns has different values?

Tags: pandas

I have two data pandas frames.

Dataframe1

```
-----------------------
id  | name | updatedat
-----------------------
1   | p1   | 2015-05-05
2   | p2   | 2015-04-29
3   | p3   | 2015-05-07
```

Dataframe2

```
------------------------
id  | name   | updatedat
------------------------
1   | p1     |2015-05-04
2   | p2     |2015-04-30
3   | t3     |2015-05-06
```

What If I want two dataframes to merge when 'id column have same value and 'name' column in each table has different value.

I want to have the result like followings.

Merged Dataframes

```
----------------------------------------------------
id  | name | updatedat   | id  | name   | updatedat
---------------------------------------------------
3   | p3   | 2015-05-07  | 3   | t3     |2015-05-06
```

But many documentation related to merge api, they just explains the cases when the value are same.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
out = df1.merge(df2, on = 'id').query('name_x!=name_y')
```

Comment: Thanks for  very quick answer :)